# Google CastCompanionLibrary license?

Tags: chromecast

Is the Google CastCompanionLibrary (https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) something that is free and open source to use on corporate Android software implementing Chromecast? Or is it just an example? Can we incorporate the library in our apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, license details is in the same project on Github.